# Reasoning for usage of the Gauß-Green theorem

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Very often, to obtain the weak formulation of some pde, the Gauß-Green theorem is used in order to get rid of the divergence, e.g. look at the $p$-Laplacian $\operatorname{div}(|Du|^{p-2}Du)$. The corresponding term in the weak formulation will be $\int D \phi \cdot |Du|^{p-2}Du$.

I understand that. But often times this is done on some domain $E$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ that doesn't have to be a $C^1$ domain, so how can the Gauß-Green theorem actually be used? May the reasoning be the following: since we can use Gauß-Green on every ball $B\subset E$, we may exploit $E$ by such balls and therefore obtain the result also on $E$. Is this correct or this the reasoning different? Thanks in advance!

Comment: First, you should still keep in mind that the divergence and Stokes' theorem are valid under far weaker assumptions than usually stated, so the regularity of the boundary of an open set $E$ can be weakened. Next, for weak formulations, we're testing against compactly supported functions so the regularity of the boundary of $E$ doesn't really matter (for any open set $E$ whatsoever, bounded/unbounded/connected/disconnected etc, if $X$ is any $C^1$ vector field with compactly support in $E$, then integrating its divergence over $E$ gives $0$).

Comment: Thanks for your answer @peek-a-boo! But the test functions don't always have compact support. What if the boundary is e.g. only attained in the Sobolev sense like $W^{1,p}_0$? Then we don't have compact support...

Comment: Then you can argue usually by density, since those are the closure of smooth compactly supported functions under the respective Sobolev norms.